# Why are the permissions of /run/user/1000 wrong

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, snap

My `/run/user/1000` directory is owned by root - as far as I understand it, it should be owned by my user - I'm unable to start any snap programs (e.g., slack) as I get this error: `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/run/user/1000/snap.slack’: Permission denied` - I also think whatever is causing this may also be causing my audio to not work.

Both of these issues can be fixed after boot by `chown` and `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload` but I'd like to figureout what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10